# Snowflake DB: XML parsing

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to parse xml data in the table into key-value pair tables. The data consist of individual product xml as a row in a snowflake table. Each product has items under it. Each of the items has item attributes. The item attributes are varying for each items. So it need to be parsed as key-value rows. Here is sample data:

```
#insert product 1 to a temp table
insert into CLAIM3 
select parse_xml($$<Product>
    <ProductNumber>P_S001</ProductNumber>
    <ProductName>Writing pad</ProductName>
    <ItemsOfProduct>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>P1_01</ItemNumber>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Size_p1_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>3-4</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>SecondaryColour_p1_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Flamingo</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Colour_p1_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Blue</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>P1_02</ItemNumber>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Size_p1_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>4-5</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>SecondaryColour_p1_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Yellow</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Colour_p1_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Red</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Item>
    </ItemsOfProduct>
</Product>
$$);

# insert product 2 to temp table
insert into CLAIM3 
select parse_xml($$<Product>
    <ProductNumber>P_S002</ProductNumber>
    <ProductName>Writing Pen</ProductName>
    <ItemsOfProduct>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>P2_01</ItemNumber>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Size_p2_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>3-4</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>SecondaryColour_p2_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Flamingo</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Colour_p2_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Blue</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>P2_02</ItemNumber>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Size_p2_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>4-5</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>SecondaryColour_p2_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Yellow</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Colour_p2_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Red</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Item>
    </ItemsOfProduct>
</Product>
$$);

# view contents of table - shows two rows - each containing the district products inserted above
SELECT * FROM CLAIM3;
```

Here is how I am parsing the data. Took reference of https://medium.com/snowflake/working-with-xml-in-snowflake-part-i-8b4eca1c01fa

```
SELECT 
XMLGET(src_xml, 'ProductNumber'):"$"::string AS SRC_PRODUCT_NUMBER,
XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(src_xml, 'ItemsOfProduct'), 'Item'), 'ItemNumber') :"$"::string AS ITEM_NUMBER,
XMLGET(attributes.value, 'AttributeID'):"$" AS ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
XMLGET(attributes.value, 'AttributeValue'):"$" AS  ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
FROM CLAIM3,
LATERAL FLATTEN(XMLGET(XMLGET(XMLGET(src_xml, 'ItemsOfProduct'), 'Item'), 'Attributes'):"$") attributes
```

[image]

The output is providing the attributes of item 1(P1_01, P2_01) of product 1 and product 2. It is skipping item 2(P1_02, P2_02) of product 1 and product 2. Can anyone help me understand what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT XMLGET(src_xml,'ProductNumber'):"$":: STRING PRODUCT_NUMBER

,XMLGET(ITEMS.VALUE,'ItemNumber'):"$"  :: STRING ITEM_NUMBER

,XMLGET(ATTRIBUTE.VALUE,'AttributeID'):"$"  :: STRING ATTRIBUTE_ID

,XMLGET(ATTRIBUTE.VALUE,'AttributeValue'):"$"  :: STRING ATTRIBUTE_VALUE



FROM CLAIM3 , LATERAL FLATTEN(src_xml:"$")  ITEMSOFPRODUCT, LATERAL FLATTEN(ITEMSOFPRODUCT.VALUE:"$")  ITEMS
 , LATERAL FLATTEN(ITEMS.VALUE:"$")  ATTRIBUTES
 
  , LATERAL FLATTEN(ATTRIBUTES.VALUE:"$")  ATTRIBUTE


--WHERE GET(ITEMS.VALUE,'@')='Item'  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work ?

The guts - I think you need to join to each level in your XML heirarchy ... e.g. two lots of lateral joins.

Let me know if this helps/solves :-)

Code can be copy/pasted and run straight into Snowflake  :-)

[image]

```
    with cte as (
    select
        parse_xml(
            $$<Product>
    <ProductNumber>P_S001</ProductNumber>
    <ProductName>Writing pad</ProductName>
    <ItemsOfProduct>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>P1_01</ItemNumber>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Size_p1_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>3-4</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>SecondaryColour_p1_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Flamingo</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Colour_p1_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Blue</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>P1_02</ItemNumber>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Size_p1_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>4-5</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>SecondaryColour_p1_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Yellow</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Colour_p1_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Red</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Item>
    </ItemsOfProduct>
</Product>
$$
        ) src_xml
    union
    select
        parse_xml(
            $$<Product>
    <ProductNumber>P2_S001</ProductNumber>
    <ProductName>Writing pad</ProductName>
    <ItemsOfProduct>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>P21_01</ItemNumber>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Size_p1_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>3-4</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>SecondaryColour_p1_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Flamingo</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Colour_p1_item1</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Blue</AttributeValue>
                </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemNumber>P21_02</ItemNumber>
            <Attributes>
                <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Size_p1_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>4-5</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>SecondaryColour_p1_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Yellow</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute>
                        <Type>Defining</Type>
                        <AttributeID>Colour_p1_item2</AttributeID>
                        <AttributeValue>Red</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
            </Attributes>
        </Item>
    </ItemsOfProduct>
</Product>
$$
        )
)
SELECT
    XMLGET(src_xml, 'ProductNumber') :"$" :: string AS SRC_PRODUCT_NUMBER,
    XMLGET(attributes.value, 'ItemNumber') :"$" :: string AS ItemNumber,
    XMLGET(at2.value, 'AttributeID') :"$" :: string Attribute_Name,
    XMLGET(at2.value, 'AttributeValue') :"$" :: string Attribute_Value
FROM
    cte,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(XMLGET(src_xml, 'ItemsOfProduct') :"$") attributes,
    lateral flatten (XMLGET(attributes.value, 'Attributes') :"$") at2
```